# How to resolve 'Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.' for enums with long values

Tags: protobuf-net

Lets say I have a enum

```
public enum PricingFlags : long
```

that has a value of 100000000000100001111111000010001_2 or 4296080913. Basically a collection of flags like

```
[Description("Aggregate")]
Aggregate = 1L << 7,
```

logical OR'ed together. I am using version 2.3.1.

I tried adding EnumPassthru in attribute

```
[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic, EnumPassthru = true)]
```

or in protobuf specification,

```
 RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(PricingFlags)].EnumPassthru = true;
```

after googling I found https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/issues/219 that told me there is a chance that it should work, but it did not. Am I doing something wrong?

---

Edit:

I ended up changing the property to have a backing field and making it a proto member and ignoring the property itself.

```
[ProtoMember(9021, Name = "Flags")]
private long _flagsValue;
...
[ProtoIgnore]
public PricingFlags Flags
{
    get => (PricingFlags)_flagsValue;
    set => _flagsValue = (long)value;
}
```

Comment: Marc pushed it back to version 2.3.2 ten days later.  It has no due-date yet.

Comment: as promised; added as test in V3; works fine: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/commit/6b605962c6607d8c6ae18677e72756efb978e259

Comment: @HansPassant closed as completed (v3) now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice for today would be: declare a shadow property (perhaps private) that exposes the data as a long, doing the cast in your code.

The V2 enum code is kinda ugly for this. I'm smashing this in V3 (basically all enums become native passthrus) so I will add these as test scenarios for V3.